# Does Percona MySQL Server 5.7.23 support multi-source replication?

Tags: mysql, database-replication, percona, multi-source-replication

We want to run multi-source replication.

```
Server version: 5.7.23-23-log Percona Server (GPL), Release '23', Revision '500fcf5'

mysql> CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_HOST='1.2.3.4', MASTER_PORT=3306, MASTER_USER='repl', MASTER_PASSWORD='xxx' for channel="master1";
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '="master1"' at line 1
```

Does latest version of Percona Server not support multi-source replication or the SQL command should be different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the correct sintax is `FOR CHANNEL 'master-1'`

Comment: Thanks a lot, not sure why all documentation is mentionning the FOR CHANNEL='master-1'